# Huge git project upgrade - How should I approach this?

Tags: git

At work we are using a web-application provided by a third-party company.
We have taken this project (got it from their git repos) and after a year we have added ~300 commits on top of the "vanillia" one.

Now a new version came out, and I am looking for the best approach to upgrade without messing many things up. Now the structure of the project, is like this:

```
Main Container App
-> plugins/git_submodule_1
-> plugins/git_submodule_2
...
..
```

We haven't changed anything in the plugins, submodules so that is great. but the problem is withing the container app.

I did a usual `git fetch`, the `git rebase origin/master`.
Gave me more than 300+ conflicts.

Is there a visual application that will help me deal with this? (instead of using the terminal)

Should I avoid rebasing for this?

Thanks

Comment: `git merge origin/master` may produce less conflicts.

Comment: You can always solve conflicts in your editor. I get a few dozen on old branches and just fix them by hand.

Comment: Use one IDE. My favorite is [IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/), but there are others, like Net Beans and Eclipse